# Update MySQL Value with checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, css

I currently have the code below (it's a mix of css and html) for toggles. Ultimately the user can toggle for a value in the database to change from 0 to 1. However, I don't know how to do this without a submit button.

**CSS:**

```
.onoffswitch {
    position: relative; width: 45px;
    -webkit-user-select:none; -moz-user-select:none; -ms-user-select: none;
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox {
    display: none;
}
.onoffswitch-label {
    display: block; overflow: hidden; cursor: pointer;
    border: 2px solid #E3E3E3; border-radius: 10px;
}
.onoffswitch-inner {
    width: 200%; margin-left: -100%;
    -moz-transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s; -webkit-transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
    -o-transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s; transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}
.onoffswitch-inner:before, .onoffswitch-inner:after {
    float: left; width: 50%; height: 15px; padding: 0; line-height: 15px;
    font-size: 7px; color: white; font-family: Trebuchet, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: bold;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;
}
.onoffswitch-inner:before {
    content: "ON";
    padding-left: 5px;
    background-color: #5B969C; color: #EEEEEE;
}
.onoffswitch-inner:after {
    content: "OFF";
    padding-right: 5px;
    background-color: #EEEEEE; color: #5B969C;
    text-align: right;
}
.onoffswitch-switch {
    width: 15px; margin: 0px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border: 2px solid #E3E3E3; border-radius: 10px;
    position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; right: 26px;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s; -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s; transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s; 
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-inner {
    margin-left: 0;
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-switch {
    right: 0px; 
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="onoffswitch">
    <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox"      id="onoffswitch6">
    <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="onoffswitch6">
        <div class="onoffswitch-inner"></div>
        <div class="onoffswitch-switch"></div>
    </label>
</div>
```

**Edit:** after the answers I added this script to the page and a PHP file. However, it only changes to 1 in the database, but doesn't change it back to 0.

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('#onoffswitch6').change(function() {
                var checked = $(this).is(':checked'); //true or false?
                $.ajax({
                    type: "post",
                    url: "encrypt.php", //PHP or whichever other language script that updates your database
                    data: { onOrOff : checked } //access this value in your script via $_POST['onOrOff'], if it's a PHP script
                    });
            });
        });
```

PHP File:

```
<?php
//Start session
session_start();

//Include database connection details
require_once('connection.php');

if(isset($_POST['onOrOff']))
{
    if ($_POST['onOrOff'] == false) {
        global $onOrOff;
        $onOrOff = 0;
    } else if ($_POST['onOrOff'] == true) {
        global $onOrOff;
        $onOrOff = 1;
    };

$qry = "UPDATE member SET value='$onOrOff' WHERE id='$_SESSION[SESS_MEMBER_ID]'";
$result = mysql_query($qry) or die("An error occurred ".mysql_error());
}
?>
```

Comment: You can use an AJAX request in an onchange handler for the checkbox, but you're going to have to give us some more info/context.

Comment: @Overv What do you need to know?

Comment: So it updates 'value' column when the checkbox is checked, but doesn't update back when the user unchecks it?

Comment: Yes, exactly. It changes 0 (= default) to 1, but not 1 to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AJAX is what you need. As I don't have much info, I'll make up a small example:

```
$('.onoffswitch-checkbox').change(function() {
    var checked = $(this).is(':checked'); //true or false?
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "myscript.php", //PHP or whichever other language script that updates your database
        data: { onOrOff : checked } //access this value in your script via $_POST['onOrOff'], if it's a PHP script
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! One more question, what will $_POST['onOrOff'] be, if it's checked? 1, checked, false?

Comment: If it's checked, it will be true. And will be false otherwise.

Comment: Actually I was wrong, sorry. The returned value would be "checked" and not true if it's checked. I'll edit my answer to make it in a way it returns true or false only, as I think it's cleaner this way.

Comment: Thanks, you're of great help, but your script only calls myscript.php if it's checked. What do I change so that it  calls myscript.php on any change?

Comment: This is odd... jQuery's "change" event is supposed to trigger both on check and uncheck. Are you sure the problem is that the script really isn't called?

Comment: Well, actually it IS called, but it's unclear what is causing the problem. It notices the check, but not the uncheck. I added the PHP to the question.

Comment: Sorry, you meant to paste the script's code? Something went wrong.

Comment: No, I was still adding it to the question ;p